# Which PNG Fix will work in this condition?

Tags: css, xhtml, png, cross-browser

I'm working with client's CMS and it's adding images like this and i can't change this.

I tried IE7.js but it's not working

```
<img src="~/imagefolder/CF88B05B445A4D008806C8B3E2830679.png?w=400&h=300&as=1" />
```

Comment: What are you talking about? :) What is your question exactly? I don't get it. And are you sure the `~` is correct in the image URL?

Comment: yes it's correct because it's working fine the problem is all PNG fixes select `.png` extension but here it is `.png?w=400&h=300&as=1`

Comment: You might have to tweak the IE7.js a bit to look for images with .png extension and .png?whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Unless whatever code runs behind *imagefolder* dislikes additional, unknown arguments, you might be able to trick the IE hack into thinking it's a .png:

```
<img src="~/imagefolder/CF88B05B445A4D008806C8B3E2830679.png?w=400&h=300&as=1&dummy=.png" />
```

Comment: i can't do this also because it's dynamic